# Sysprep for EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2, sysprep, cloning

[AWS' documents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ami-create-standard.html) on creating a custom image reference using sysprep as one of the steps in the creation process.  They don't actually specify if it's a required step or if it is run automatically as part of the create image option from the instance context menu.  I know that it is best practice to run sysprep when you image a machine for cloning but AWS has seemed to automate a lot of the cloning process. So...my question is.

Does anyone know if when you create an image from an instance that is currently in the running state does the create image process run sysprep on the new image before it makes it available for use in creating new instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an AMI of a running EC2 instance, whether from the AWS Management Console, AWS CLI, or other SDK, sysprep is not executed.

If want to run sysprep, you must sign in to execute it. You may be able to run it via the EC2 Run Command feature, but I don't have evidence. You would need to be able to execute it without UI.